# Use polymorphic relation in index.blade in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

Before this, I do not use polymorphic relation. I only use `user_id` for each table such as Admin, Buyer and Contractor to relate it with User table. Now, I'm able to use polymorphic relation since I need to use `name` and `avatar` column from those 3 tables in navigation bar. Every time the users login into their account, they will see their name and avatar on the navigation bar.

**user table**

```
id
role
email
typable_id
typable_type
```

**buyers table**

```
id 
name
address
phone_no
email
avatar
```

**User.php**

```
public function typable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**Buyer.php**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'typable');
    }
```

That's already fixed my problem. But the problem now, how can I use polymorphic relation for my index view? This is the previous query that I use when I used user_id.

**BuyerController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role == 'buyer')
            {     
                $buyers = Buyer::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
                return view('buyers.index',['buyer'=>$buyers]);
            }
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="profile-main">
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/{{auth()->user()->typable->avatar}}" width="100" length="100" class="img-circle" alt="Avatar">
    <h3 class="name">{{$buyer->name}}</h3>
</div>

<div class="profile-detail">
   <div class="profile-info">
       <h4 class="heading"><b><center>Resident's Details</center></b></h4>
           <ul class="list-unstyled list-justify">
               <li><b>Buyer ID: </b>{{$buyer->buyer_id}}</li>
               <li><b>Name: </b>{{$buyer->name}}</li>
               <li><b>Address: </b>{{$buyer->address}}</li>
               <li><b>Phone Number: </b>{{$buyer->phone_no}}</li>
               <li><b>Email: </b>{{$buyer->email}}</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
<div class="text-center"><a href="/buyer/{{$buyer->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Profile</a></div>
```

When I login using the buyer's account, this is the error that I got `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from` buyers`where`user_id `= 8 limit 1)` and `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Comment: what is `residential`? you are only showing a relationship named `user` for Buyer ... and by the error message from the sql `buyers` table does not have a `user_id` column so not sure why you are trying to use that column

Comment: you can ignore the residential because that is another type of relationship that I already make it. for error `user_id` that is because the query that I used in index.blade is before I make polymorphic relation. Now I want to know what query I should do in the index.blade if I use polymorphic relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$buyers = Buyer::find(Auth::user()->typable_id);
```